# How to tokenize a string in Oracle and convert each token to NUMBER to use them in a query as part of IN clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a string '1,2,3'

I want to tokenize the string and convert each of the tokens into NUMBER. So the above string will be tokenized into :

```
        1      NUMBER
        2      NUMBER
        3      NUMBER
```

The final intention is to use them in a query as part of IN clause as below :

select * from sample where type in (1,2,3) ;

How can I achieve this ? One important point here is the string can have different number of tokens in different situations. So it can be either '1,2,3' or '1,2' or '1,2,3,4' or even '1'.

Please help me out guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
with test as 
(
    select '1,2,3' str from dual  
)  
select * from sample 
where type in(
      select regexp_substr (str, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) split  
      from test  
      connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (str, '[^,]+'))  + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing, it might be faster to convert the id to a String and look for it in your String. Just add a comma to the beginning and the end of your list.

```
SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS id FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 3 FROM DUAL) idtable
 WHERE ',' || '1,3,4,5' || ',' LIKE '%,' || idtable.id || ',%'
```